# play HTML5-videos in WebView?

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video from my WebView, I've solved it... well sort of, but there is one problem. As for now, I've added an image with an onclick function named "playVideo"

```
public void playVideo(View V)
{
    String LINK = "*URL TO VIDEO*";
    setContentView(R.layout.video_activity);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
}
```

When you press it, it opens up an activity with a "VideoView".

The problem:
I'm loading the video from a server and there will be new videos that will be uploaded and I would like to implement support for videos beeing played (run the "playVideo"-method) straight from the webpage that the webview shows.

Hope you understand what I mean.
Basicly; I want to click the < video >-tag (html5) open up video_activity and play video.

Answer (score 1):

I may have inadvertently posted this answer previously in the wrong place...
I converted the video file to a base64 string and fed it directly into the source, vola! The webview is no longer confused by the asset location

```
<video width="400"  height="225" controls="controls" align="center" poster="data:image/poster.jpg" >
<source id="bigd" src="data:video/mp4;charset=utf-8;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1...(etc.)">
</video>
```

Comment: I thought the problem was that the WebView wasnt able to read video-tags?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the asset location hence including the asset in the actual page...this sort of worked, but rather than a final solution it proved to be a bit of a blind alley...